# After deploying the approuter to cloud foundry, the app is getting crashed

Tags: s4sdk

I followed the steps on this 
[blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/18/step-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-secure-your-application-on-sap-cloud-platform-cloudfoundry/)
and deployed the After I deployed the approuter to cloud foundry, the app is getting crashed.

Below is the error log.

```
2018-04-11T15:26:11.61-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-111-generic
2018-04-11T15:26:11.61-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! argv “/home/vcap/deps/0/node/bin/node” “/home/vcap/deps/0/bin/npm” “start”
2018-04-11T15:26:11.61-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! node v6.13.1
2018-04-11T15:26:11.61-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
2018-04-11T15:26:11.61-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! path /home/vcap/app/package.json
2018-04-11T15:26:11.61-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! code ENOENT
2018-04-11T15:26:11.61-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! errno -2
2018-04-11T15:26:11.61-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! syscall open
2018-04-11T15:26:11.62-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ‘/home/vcap/app/package.json’
2018-04-11T15:26:11.62-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ‘/home/vcap/app/package.json’
2018-04-11T15:26:11.62-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
2018-04-11T15:26:11.62-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
2018-04-11T15:26:11.62-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! enoent
2018-04-11T15:26:11.62-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2018-04-11T15:26:11.62-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
```

The error log says package.json file is missing, but i placed package.json file  inside the approuter directory.

Below is the code in manifest.json file.

```
---
applications:
 - name: approuter
   host: approuter-s0018349215trial
   path: approuter
   memory: 128M
   buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
   env:
        TENANT_HOST_PATTERN: '*****'
        destinations: '[{"name":"Businesspartners_cloudfoundry", "url" 
        :"https://***********", "forwardAuthToken": true}]'
   services:
     - my-xsuaa
```

Below is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "@sap/approuter",
  "description": "Node.js based application router",
  "version": "2.10.0",
  "repository": {},
  "main": "approuter.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "agentkeepalive": "2.0.5",
    "async": "2.0.1",
    "basic-auth": "1.0.3",
    "commander": "2.9.0",
    "compression": "1.6.0",
    "connect": "3.6.2",
    "cookie": "0.2.2",
    "cookie-parser": "1.3.5",
    "cookie-signature": "1.0.6",
    "express-session": "1.15.3",
    "http-proxy-agent": "1.0.0",
    "https-proxy-agent": "1.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "2.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "lru-cache": "4.0.0",
    "mustache": "2.2.1",
    "passport": "0.3.2",
    "request": "2.81.0",
    "request-stats": "2.0.1",
    "safe-regex": "1.1.0",
    "@sap/audit-logging": "^1.0.5",
    "@sap/e2e-trace": "^1.1.2",
    "@sap/logging": "^3.0.0",
    "@sap/xsenv": "^1.2.6",
    "send": "0.15.3",
    "serve-static": "1.12.3",
    "tough-cookie": "2.3.1",
    "tv4": "1.2.7",
    "urijs": "1.16.1",
    "verror": "1.10.0",
    "ws": "1.1.4",
    "base64-url": "1.2.1",
    "scmp": "1.0.0",
    "uid-safe": "~2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.15.2",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "diveSync": "0.3.0",
    "eslint": "3.2.2",
    "filter-node-package": "^2.0.0",
    "istanbul": "0.4.4",
    "markdown-toc": "^1.1.0",
    "mocha": "3.0.2",
    "node-build": "^1.0.0",
    "node-mocks-http": "1.5.2",
    "node-style": "^2.0.0",
    "proxyquire": "1.7.10",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "sinon": "1.17.5",
    "supertest": "2.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^0.12.7 || ^4.4.0 || ^6.0.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib",
    "doc",
    "package.json",
    "README.md",
    "approuter.js"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node approuter.js",
    "test": "node build/test",
    "lint": "eslint -c node_modules/node-style/.eslintrc -f stylish lib/ approuter.js",
    "toc": "markdown-toc -i README.md && markdown-toc -i doc/extending.md && markdown-toc -i doc/sizingGuide.md",
    "prepareRelease": "node build/delete-extra-packages.js && clean-packages && npm prune --production"
  }
}
```

Below is the screenshot of working directory.

[image]

Below is the screenshot of approuter directory

[image]

A different error is coming up on deploying cf push command with below error log.

> > 2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR /home/vcap/app/lib/utils/JsonValidator.js:30
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     throw new
> >     VError('%s%s: %s',    2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR
> >     ^    2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR VError:
> >     environment-settings/tenantHostPattern: Format validation failed
> >     (regular expression must contain a capturing group)
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
> >     JsonValidator.validate
> >     (/home/vcap/app/lib/utils/JsonValidator.js:30:11)
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
> >     Object.validateEnvironmentSettings
> >     (/home/vcap/app/lib/configuration/validators.js:106:15)
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
> >     loadGroupedConfigurations
> >     (/home/vcap/app/lib/configuration/env-config.js:146:14)
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.load
> >     (/home/vcap/app/lib/configuration/env-config.js:28:17)
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
> >     Object.module.exports.load (/home/vcap/app/lib/configuration.js:15:37)
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at bootstrap
> >     (/home/vcap/app/lib/bootstrap.js:47:36)    2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400
> >     [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Approuter.start
> >     (/home/vcap/app/approuter.js:58:13)    2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400
> >     [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.
> >     (/home/vcap/app/approuter.js:115:6)    2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400
> >     [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.02-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
> >     Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Linux
> >     4.4.0-116-generic    2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/deps/0/node/bin/node"
> >     "/home/vcap/deps/0/bin/npm" "start"    2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400
> >     [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! node v6.13.1
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! npm 
> >     v3.10.10    2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!
> >     code ELIFECYCLE    2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR
> >     npm ERR! @sap/approuter@2.10.0 start: `node approuter.js`
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Exit status
> >     1    2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Failed at
> >     the @sap/approuter@2.10.0 start script 'node approuter.js'.
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Make sure
> >     you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! If you do,
> >     this is most likely a problem with the @sap/approuter package,
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! not with npm
> >     itself.    2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!
> >     Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!     node
> >     approuter.js    2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm
> >     ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project
> >     with:    2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!
> >     npm bugs @sap/approuter    2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400
> >     [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get
> >     their info via:    2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR
> >     npm ERR!     npm owner ls @sap/approuter
> >     2018-04-23T09:27:34.04-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! There is
> >     likely additional logging output above.    2018-04-23T09:27:34.05-0400
> >     [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with
> >     any support request:    2018-04-23T09:27:34.05-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
> >     ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log

Below is the output on executing the cf push command.

> Uploading approuter... Uploading app files from:
>   C:\Users\sanke\Desktop\favLocation\approuter Uploading 3.3M, 4197
>   files Done uploading OK Binding service my-xsuaa to app approuter in
>   org P1942820265trial_trial / space dev as
>   sankeerthnarsina@gmail.com... OK
>
> Starting app approuter in org P1942820265trial_trial / space dev as
>   sankeerthnarsina@gmail.com... Downloading nodejs_buildpack... Cell
>   09aeff0a-17aa-40ac-aee3-dcf077acd6c9 successfully created container
>   for instance 6485e7e3-0b40-4db3-8880-dba968c55583 Downloaded
>   nodejs_buildpack Cell 09aeff0a-17aa-40ac-aee3-dcf077acd6c9 creating
>   container for instance 6485e7e3-0b40-4db3-8880-dba968c55583
>   Downloading app package... Downloaded app package (4.5M)
>   -----> Nodejs Buildpack version 1.6.20
>   -----> Installing binaries
>          engines.node (package.json): ^0.12.7 || ^4.4.0 || ^6.0.0
>          engines.npm (package.json): unspecified (use default)
>   -----> Installing node 6.13.1
>          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/node/node-6.13.1-linux-x64-fc51b8dd.tgz]
>          Using default npm version: 3.10.10
>   -----> Installing yarn 1.5.1
>          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/yarn/yarn-v1.5.1-cd316572.tar.gz]
>          Installed yarn 1.5.1
>   -----> Creating runtime environment
>          NODE_ENV=production
>          NODE_HOME=/tmp/contents135652367/deps/0/node
>          NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
>          NODE_VERBOSE=false
>          NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
>          NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
>   -----> Restoring cache
>          Skipping cache restore (no previous cache)
>   -----> Building dependencies
>          Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
>          Rebuilding any native modules agentkeepalive@2.0.5 /tmp/app/node_modules/agentkeepalive async@2.0.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/async lodash@4.17.4 /tmp/app/node_modules/lodash
>   basic-auth@1.0.3 /tmp/app/node_modules/basic-auth commander@2.9.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/commander graceful-readlink@1.0.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/graceful-readlink compression@1.6.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/compression accepts@1.3.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/accepts negotiator@0.6.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/negotiator mime-types@2.1.16
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/mime-types mime-db@1.29.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/mime-db compressible@2.0.11
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/compressible vary@1.1.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/vary bytes@2.1.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/bytes
>   on-headers@1.0.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/on-headers debug@2.2.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/compression/node_modules/debug ms@0.7.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/compression/node_modules/ms connect@3.6.2
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/connect debug@2.6.7 /tmp/app/node_modules/debug
>   ms@2.0.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/ms finalhandler@1.0.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/finalhandler parseurl@1.3.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/parseurl escape-html@1.0.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/escape-html encodeurl@1.0.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/encodeurl unpipe@1.0.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/unpipe on-finished@2.3.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/on-finished ee-first@1.1.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/ee-first statuses@1.3.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/statuses utils-merge@1.0.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/utils-merge cookie@0.2.2
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/cookie cookie-parser@1.3.5
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/cookie-parser cookie-signature@1.0.6
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/cookie-signature cookie@0.1.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/cookie-parser/node_modules/cookie
>   express-session@1.15.3 /tmp/app/node_modules/express-session
>   depd@1.1.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/depd uid-safe@2.1.4
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/express-session/node_modules/uid-safe
>   random-bytes@1.0.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/random-bytes crc@3.4.4
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/crc cookie@0.3.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/express-session/node_modules/cookie
>   http-proxy-agent@1.0.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/http-proxy-agent
>   agent-base@2.1.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/agent-base semver@5.0.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/semver extend@3.0.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/extend
>   https-proxy-agent@1.0.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/https-proxy-agent
>   jwt-decode@2.0.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/jwt-decode lru-cache@4.0.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/lru-cache pseudomap@1.0.2
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/pseudomap yallist@2.1.2
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/yallist mustache@2.2.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/mustache passport@0.3.2
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/passport pause@0.0.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/pause
>   passport-strategy@1.0.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/passport-strategy
>   request@2.81.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/request performance-now@0.2.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/performance-now stringstream@0.0.5
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/stringstream aws4@1.6.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/aws4 uuid@3.1.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/uuid
>   tunnel-agent@0.6.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/tunnel-agent
>   safe-buffer@5.1.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/safe-buffer tough-cookie@2.3.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/tough-cookie is-typedarray@1.0.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/is-typedarray http-signature@1.1.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/http-signature sshpk@1.13.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/sshpk asn1@0.2.3 /tmp/app/node_modules/asn1
>   getpass@0.1.7 /tmp/app/node_modules/getpass assert-plus@1.0.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/assert-plus dashdash@1.14.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/dashdash assert-plus@0.2.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/assert-plus
>   jsprim@1.4.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/jsprim json-schema@0.2.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/json-schema verror@1.3.6
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/jsprim/node_modules/verror extsprintf@1.0.2
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/jsprim/node_modules/extsprintf
>   har-validator@4.2.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/har-validator
>   har-schema@1.0.5 /tmp/app/node_modules/har-schema ajv@4.11.8
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/ajv co@4.6.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/co
>   json-stable-stringify@1.0.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/json-stable-stringify jsonify@0.0.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/jsonify aws-sign2@0.6.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/aws-sign2 hawk@3.1.3 /tmp/app/node_modules/hawk
>   sntp@1.0.9 /tmp/app/node_modules/sntp hoek@2.16.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/hoek boom@2.10.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/boom
>   cryptiles@2.0.5 /tmp/app/node_modules/cryptiles qs@6.4.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/qs json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/json-stringify-safe caseless@0.12.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/caseless isstream@0.1.2
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/isstream form-data@2.1.4
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/form-data asynckit@0.4.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/asynckit combined-stream@1.0.5
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/combined-stream delayed-stream@1.0.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/delayed-stream oauth-sign@0.8.2
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/oauth-sign forever-agent@0.6.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/forever-agent request-stats@2.0.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/request-stats http-headers@3.0.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/http-headers next-line@1.1.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/next-line once@1.4.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/once
>   wrappy@1.0.2 /tmp/app/node_modules/wrappy safe-regex@1.1.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/safe-regex ret@0.1.14 /tmp/app/node_modules/ret
>   @sap/audit-logging@1.0.5 /tmp/app/node_modules/@sap/audit-logging
>   moment@2.15.2 /tmp/app/node_modules/moment winston@1.1.2
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/winston eyes@0.1.8 /tmp/app/node_modules/eyes
>   pkginfo@0.3.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/pkginfo colors@1.0.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/colors async@1.0.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async stack-trace@0.0.10
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/stack-trace cycle@1.0.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/cycle @sap/e2e-trace@1.1.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/@sap/e2e-trace @sap/logging@3.0.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/@sap/logging lodash@4.13.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/@sap/logging/node_modules/lodash
>   @sap/xsenv@1.2.7 /tmp/app/node_modules/@sap/xsenv verror@1.10.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/verror core-util-is@1.0.2
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/core-util-is extsprintf@1.3.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/extsprintf send@0.15.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/send range-parser@1.2.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/range-parser http-errors@1.6.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/http-errors inherits@2.0.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/inherits depd@1.1.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/http-errors/node_modules/depd
>   setprototypeof@1.0.3 /tmp/app/node_modules/setprototypeof etag@1.8.0
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/etag mime@1.3.4 /tmp/app/node_modules/mime
>   fresh@0.5.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/fresh destroy@1.0.4
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/destroy serve-static@1.12.3
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/serve-static tv4@1.2.7 /tmp/app/node_modules/tv4
>   urijs@1.16.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/urijs ws@1.1.4
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/ws ultron@1.0.2 /tmp/app/node_modules/ultron
>   options@0.0.6 /tmp/app/node_modules/options base64-url@1.2.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/base64-url scmp@1.0.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/scmp
>   uid-safe@2.0.0 /tmp/app/node_modules/uid-safe bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/bcrypt-pbkdf tweetnacl@0.14.5
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/tweetnacl ecc-jsbn@0.1.1
>   /tmp/app/node_modules/ecc-jsbn jsbn@0.1.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/jsbn
>          Installing any new modules (package.json)
>   -----> Caching build
>          Clearing previous node cache
>          Saving 3 cacheDirectories (default):
>          - .npm (nothing to cache)
>          - .cache/yarn (nothing to cache)
>          - bower_components (nothing to cache) Exit status 0 Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache... Uploading build artifacts cache...
>   Uploading droplet... Uploaded build artifacts cache (14.3M) Uploaded
>   droplet (17.6M) Uploading complete Cell
>   09aeff0a-17aa-40ac-aee3-dcf077acd6c9 stopping instance
>   6485e7e3-0b40-4db3-8880-dba968c55583 Cell
>   09aeff0a-17aa-40ac-aee3-dcf077acd6c9 destroying container for instance
>   6485e7e3-0b40-4db3-8880-dba968c55583 Cell
>   09aeff0a-17aa-40ac-aee3-dcf077acd6c9 successfully destroyed container
>   for instance 6485e7e3-0b40-4db3-8880-dba968c55583
>
> 0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting 0 of 1 instances running, 1
>   crashed FAILED Error restarting application: Start unsuccessful

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Could you please post your manifest.yml file. However, please, omit sensitive data.

Comment: Sure! I posted the manifest.yml file as an update for this question.

Comment: Just to make sure: So you called the `cf push` command from the directory containing the posted `manifest.yml` file (mind the extension) as well as a directory named `approuter` which contains the `package.json` file?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i did

Comment: I also followed the [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/troubleshoot-app-health.html) to resolve this issue. But the issue is not resolved.

Comment: Can you also please show the package.json file itself and post your working directory structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I updated the question with package.json file and screenshot for working directory structure.

Comment: Very strange. Just tried it with your package.json and it works for me on the CF Trial Landscape. Further questions: 1) On which landscape is the AppRouter supposed to be deployed? 2) Could you please also share the content from the approuter directory in another screenshot? 3) Apparently you used the AppRouter from the SAP Service Marketplace. Did you do any modifications to it (e.g., npm install) except putting the xs-app.json there?

Comment: 1) I am trying to deploy it to Cloud foundry Landscape. 2) updated the question with screenshot for approuter directory. 3) Yes, i downloaded the approuter from SAP Market place but i didn't make any changes except adding xs-app.json file.

Comment: Could you please post the first few lines of the output from the cf push command. In particular, the path after "Uploading approuter... Uploading app files from: ..." would be interesting. Could you provide this as well. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to deploy the approuter using the cf push command again, but this time it gave a different error. I updated the question with this error log and first few lines of output from cf push command. Please review.

Comment: Ok, so you are now definitively uploading the correct directory, since the output says "Uploading app files from: ~\Desktop\favLocation\approuter". My hypothesis is that in the past something was wrong that uploaded a different directory, maybe favLocation instead of favLocation\approuter (e.g., wrong indentation in manifest.yml could easily lead to this). Now you got a different issue where I will answer separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log message indicates that the the environment variable for the `TENANT_HOST_PATTERN` variable cannot be correctly parsed: `ERR VError: environment-settings/tenantHostPattern: Format validation failed (regular expression must contain a capturing group)`.

Please specify a correct regular expression for the `TENANT_HOST_PATTERN` variable in `manifest.yml` such as `approuter-(.*).cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com` (please note to replace the domain with the landscape that you are deploying to).

Alternatively, you may set the variable via `cf set-env approuter TENANT_HOST_PATTERN 'approuter-(.*).cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com'` followed by a `cf restage approuter` command.